# Are there more volumes of THE BREAKER?

Tags: the-breaker

I recently read the manga THE BREAKER: NEW WAVES. Is there a continuation of this manga? It ended in a rather uncomfortable state (personal view).

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: WELl google search didnt show me anything AFTER the new waves volume(there is one before that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no continuation for The Breaker: New Waves for now. The author took a break on this series and started Trinity Wonder, if I remember right.

Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional information to Soukatsoui's correct answer.

The Breaker: New Waves went on a hiatus in May 2015 before releasing Part 3 of the Manhwa. The reason is stated as the author will be working on another supposedly "mid-size" comic "Trinity Wonder".

The actual duration of this break hasn't been announced. From initial optimistic estimate of 6-12 months, it looks the break will last for atleast 3 years. So I wouldn't expect any more Breaker chapters before 2018.

TL;DR The Breaker is on an **indefinite hiatus pending update from the author** about the release of Part 3.

In October 2015, we got a look at the panel, which may be from part 3, so the author may still be working on it on the side.
http://m.blog.naver.com/tdstudio/220481432104

I'd found this Reddit when I was thinking of picking Breaker back up thinking it was finished (https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/4dsrxi/breakers_creators_work_on_a_new_comic_called/)

Comment: Panel is most likely from Trinity Wonder, as new manhwa has very similar design to Breaker.

Comment: @lentinant I said maybe. Though haven't taken a look at trinity wonder, so can't comment. I was just optimistic I guess :)